# Multiple instances of sound (SoundJS)

Tags: createjs, soundjs

I'm using SoundJS to manage audio in a html5 game we're building.
Simplified: we have a song playing in the background and a voice track playing at the same time.

I now would like to use an analyser on the voice track to animate one of the characters. We basically want to do a very rudimentary lipsync implementation.

However, since sound.js uses a single context (as it should), I'm unable to destinguish between music and voice. Therefor I was wondering if it was possible to start two instances of create.js sound (and thus have two seperate contexts, so I can analyse only the voice track).

Thanks!
Thijs

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was wrongly assuming that I could only attach the analyser to the output node, but I can also attach it to basically anything. That solved it :)